# How to use the Fedora 22 Cloud RAW (.raw) image on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, fedora

I've downloaded the RAW image of Fedora 22 Cloud to use/install on my VirtualBox installation under Windows but just don't know how to use it. I understand that it may be a dd copy of a filesystem but I don't know for sure which filesystem it is and what to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to need to convert your `RAW` image to `.VDI` or some other format of VirtualDisk so that VirtuaBox knows what to do with it.

Here's a native VirtualBox command I've used in the past to convert `.RAW` images (made with `dd` cloning command) into `.VDI` format

Try this:
`VBoxManage convertdd YourFedoraImage.raw NewNameForYourFedoraImage.vdi --format VDI`

It goes without saying that your terminal/command line needs to be in the VirtualBox installation folder in order to use `VBoxManage`.
I originally got this one liner from [this](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/04/29/virtualbox-convert-raw-image-to-vdi-and-otherwise/) post. It has several one liners for using `VBoxManage` to convert `.RAW` images into several different formats. ie: `.VDI`, `.VMDK` and/or back to `.RAW`.